# Android Video player developed doesn't come in the list of the video players

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I will be very discrete about what I want.

I have developed an android video player. But it is not visible in the list of video players when I click on a video file.

Suppose I go into an explorer and click on the video file. So it shows me a list of video players such as:

1. ES Video player
2. Movie player

and more...

What other implementations are required to make it get listed in the list of video-players ?

Comment: Did you add intent-filter for your activity in Manifest file?

Comment: Yep it worked. I hadn't done that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this node to your activity in ANdroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />                        
     <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
</intent-filter>
```